# Keeping a service running in all activities of an app

Tags: android, service, android-activity

How do I keep a service running, when all activities of an application are viewable. and close the service only when I leave the app?

Is there a way to start a service in one activity of an app and stop that same service in another activity of that same application?

I don`t want that service to continue running when the user leaves the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no concept of 'application' and leaving it. What happens if open a link from one of your activities, launch the browser to view it, then come back via the back button? Did you really leave the app?

What does your service do? Do activities bind to it? If so, it will be automatically shut down after the last client unbinds. If not, it should shut itself when it has finished doing it's work (Cf. `IntentService`). If it doesn't fit either of those patterns, maybe you don't need a service at all, just some background thread(s)?

Edit (based on comments below):

For a service running a media player, the usual way is to have an ongoing notification for the service that lets the user bring up an activity to control the service. Or have buttons on the notification in JB to achieve something similar. Additionally, if you make the service a foreground one, that will give it higher priority and it is less likely to be killed if resources are low.

Comment: I was viewing my app as a tree structure where the single top level activity is the starting point.  and it branches out to many other activities under it with use of button links. so when the user leaves or is not viewing any of those activities then the service should shutdown.  In this context I defined one app as all the activities running under one process. they could be several threads, but one process.  and as one artistic unit.  other apps are in different processes.  are you suggesting I use binding to connect my service to all the activities?  it could be the answer.

Comment: Technically you can have multiple processes in your 'app', so the one-process thing doesn't really apply to android. What does your service do and how do activities depend on it?

Comment: the service starts an audio player running mediaplayer class to play some mp3 files. and the activities that bind to it are the 5 activities of the app.  so only when the user is currently viewing one of the 5 activites is when the music should play. after the user hits the back button or home button and go to something other than the 5 activities the service should shut down.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to have an ongoing notification for the service, that lets the user bring up an activity to stop the service. Or have buttons on the notification in JB. You can't really know where you will end up when you press the back button, so this doesn't really work on Android. You could probably have some global static state and update in each of your activities `onStop()`, but that is hackish. You might want to read this for some perspective: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: you read my mind, I was thinking about some sort of global static variable that would store the mediaplayer status information.  instead it looks like the best way is a status bar notification that the user can click and go back to the activity to pause the music.